# ExtractToFile vs ExtractToDirectory

Tags: c#, file-io, extract

I have some code that is extracting a file to a directory.  In the code below Global.fullpath is the full path to the file its self where as Global.path is the path to the directory.  This code works:

```
 private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        AppendTextBox("Extracting Files...\r\n");
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Global.fullPath, Global.path);
    }
```

However I am trying to do an overwrite if any files exist so I have this code which doesn't seem to extract anything even when there are no existing files:

```
 private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        AppendTextBox("Extracting Files...\r\n");
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(Global.fullPath))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                AppendTextBox("Extracting file: " + entry.FullName + "...\r\n");
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(Global.path, entry.FullName), true);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Does the archive.Entries have any items?

Comment: Yeah, it shows that it contains 5 items.

Comment: How does Global.path look like? And the entry.FullName? The code looks OK. Do you have the permissions to create a file there?

Comment: Global.path shows as "C:\\users\\user\\Downloads"
entry.FullName shows as "Daily Routes/"

Comment: Are you sure `Path.Combine(Global.path, entry.FullName)` creates a valid path?

Comment: "Daily Routes\" is not a valid file name.

Comment: Daily Routes is a folder that contains some items in it.  How should a folder be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, if you're trying to extract a directory `ExtractToFile()` is not going to do what you expect. Directories can't be easily overwritten like files. I think you have two options:

1. Check if the directory specified by FullName exists, and delete it before writing.
2. Check if the directory specified by FullName exists, and then rename your folder you're going to write something like `FullName = FullName + "_Copy";`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check if the combined path is a valid filename. The ExtractToFile method expects a path that ends with the filename, and some Zip archives can contain folders. In such a case, the entry.FullName property results in an invalid path.